# In C++11, is … considered an operator?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, operator-precedence

I was wondering whether … was considered an operator in C++11. And if it’s the case, what’s its precedence?

For instance consider this pretty bad example and assume ... is an operator.

```
template<typename T, typename...Args>
void foo(T _elm, Args... _args)
{
   bar(something,_args...);
}
```

How can I know whether `bar` will be run with its first parameter being `something` and `args...` expanded, or if its gonna be run on the result of `operator,(something, _args...)` ? (bonus question: can operators be overloaded with variadic templates ?)

Comment: "can operators be overloaded with variadic templates" No. Or at least, you wouldn't get anything by doing it. Operators always take a specific number of parameters.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396065/c-overloading-operator-comma-for-variadic-arguments).

Comment: @Nicol `operetor()` can take as many arguments as you want it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I was wondering whether … was considered an operator in C++11**

No, `...` is definitely not considered an operator in C++ 11. If you remember, it was also used in the previous standard in error handling

```
catch(...)
```

and though I am not sure how the `...` is analysed and parsed internally, it is definitely not treated as an operator.

**Can operators be overloaded with variadic templates ?**

I'm not sure, but I don't think so. Operators have to take a specified set of parameters like:

```
int operator + (int param1, my_obj param2);
```

I don't think it would work with variadic templates.