# Replicating C++/CLI multidimensional array template class in standard C++

Tags: c++

In C++/CLI, you can specify the following for multidimensional arrays.

```
array<int, 2>^ Foo = gcnew array<int, 2>(10);
Foo[0, 0] = 1;
Foo[1, 0] = 2;
// ...
```

I'm trying to replicate the above in the closest syntax possible in standard C++ (C++11 is allowed) via a templated class called my_array.

e.g.

```
template <typename T, int rank = 1>
    class my_array { };
```

Is it possible via some comma operator overloading tricks to achieve C++/CLI's syntax under standard C++, along with overriding my_array's subscript operator?

Ideally, I'd like the my_array used this way (equivalent to the above example):

```
my_array<int, 2> Foo = // ... (ignore this part - already implemented)
Foo[0, 0] = 1;
Foo[1, 0] = 2;
// ...
```

In case anyone's wondering, I'm creating a C++/CLI equivalent for GCC and currently the framework does not support multidimensional arrays. I'm looking to add that functionality in the closest possible way syntax wise to C++/CLI.

Comment: Why not simply use nested `std::vector` or `std::array`? It won't have the same syntax, but it's much less code you have to write.

Comment: `Foo[0][0]` is more intuitive than `Foo[0,0]` and you can achieve that with nested `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>`.

Comment: Like I said, I'm creating C++/CLI for GCC. If you don't use std::array / std::vector with C++/CLI's managed pointers, you won't use it here too.

Comment: @ZachSaw: Creating a C++/CLI language (it is a different language!) on top of plain C++ is a quite hard endeavor. You might want to consider dropping this issue (i.e. marking as *not currently supported*) and try to solve some of the harder issues as how are you going to integrate the garbage collector, how are you going to treat the managed references (`^`) or how to integrate your *managed* objects with managed languages like C#.

Comment: @David: I won't be integrating with C#. C++/CLI is powerful enough to bring a lot of the modern idioms and design patterns into C++ without having to resort to have things like enabled_shared_from_this and pitfalls where one cannot use make_shared_from_this in the ctor. GC is already sorted via BoehmGC in precise mode (similar to how Mono and GJC use it). Anyway, I think I'll do as you said and mark it as not supported. Or, introduce a multidim_array with `Foo(0, 0) = 1` as the subscript syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible in standard C++. Indeed `operator[]` can only take a single argument.

You may achieve similar syntax using one of these solutions:

- `operator()` with several arguments like `array(i, j)`
- Use a proxy class  for arguments, e.g. `array[makeIndex(i, j)]`
- Using comma operator: `array[makeIndex(i), makeIndex(j)]`
- Or `array[IndexBegin, i, j]`.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936399/c-array-operator-with-multiple-arguments) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396065/c-overloading-operator-comma-for-variadic-arguments) questions.

-- Optimization note --

In you go the comma route, you'll be building dynamic lists with the comma operator, and the array will be checking the length of these lists. In a naive implementation these checks will be run-time and redundant (when used in a loop).

Better option: use lists of statically known length (with templates) Like `IndexBegin` is IndexList<0>, `IndexList<N> [comma] int` is `IndexList<N+1>`. Then if your array also know its dimension statically, like a 2D array is `Array<2>` then you can check at compile time that a 2D array only accepts 2 indices.

Comment: It will work and didn't his 4th bullet point `array[IndexBegin, i, j]` cover that? I was just wondering if there's a more natural syntax than that.

Comment: You can overload [] to work with ints and index-lists so you can use `array[i]` and only if there are multiple indices use `array[multi, i,  j]`. But you won't be able to have the `array[i,j]` syntax.

Comment: I was replying to Joachim Pileborg who said he didn't know if overriding the comma operator is possible. I replied by saying it will and that your 4th bullet point covers it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++23, you can use this syntax in standard C++.
Related Links:
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2128r6.pdf
https://eel.is/c++draft/over.sub